# Is not a function trying find a element with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I have this code, for get an element with `getElementsByTagName` method, `d`  var is correct, you can see in the `console.log(d)`, but it not work with the method of find elements, so, what is the error ?

Error:

> d.getElementsByTagName is not a function

```js
function main(w, d) {
 console.log(d); // Works
 const CANVAS = d.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; // No works..
 console.log(CANVAS);
}

window.addEventListener("load", main.bind(window, document));
```

```html
<title>Hello world </title>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is a method of a `document` object, of which your variable is not.

Comment: You don't need `.bind` here. Try `window.addEventListener("load", main(window, document));`

Comment: @kkk You'll need to wrap `main(...)` in a function, otherwise it gets called right away, not when the event is fired

Comment: @MattClark its supposed that is document.

Comment: @KKK i need `bind()` method, to execute when the event is ready

Comment: You are using `.bind` incorrectly. First argument becomes `this` http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/bind 
it should be `.bind(null, window, document)`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `bind` is the bound `this` object. You should either change the bind statement to `main.bind(null, window, document)`
or change the main function to:

```
function main(d, event) { // supposing you will use the dom event 
 console.log(d); 
 const CANVAS = d.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; // No works..
 console.log(CANVAS);
}
```

What you seeing now from `console.log(d)` is the event object that is passed by addEventListener